# Is Mrs Dash vegan?

Tags: veganism, health, food

Is [Mrs Dash](http://www.mrsdash.com/) vegan? I’m asking mostly out of curiosity, since we’ve got a vegetarian living at our house and we’ve got Mrs Dash here as well.

Comment: If you've got a *vegetarian* at your house, wouldn't it be enough if Mrs Dash was *vegetarian*? You can, of course, ask what you want, I just found the discrepancy a bit odd. Well, since you did not include any specifics about what Mrs Dash is and Googling returns a whole range of products from the brand, I think you will first have to specify which product you have in mind before anyone can answer you.It would seem, based on a random sampling, that none of their products (blends, marinades, packets) contain animal derived ingredients. Do not take my word for it though.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderRossa I just wanted to be sure & I wasn’t sure how to spell vegetarian at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all of the [Mrs. Dash](http://www.mrsdash.com/products/seasoning-blends) **seasoning blends** are vegan. For those who are unfamiliar with Mrs. Dash seasoning blends, they are a prepackaged mix of spices. Most formulas include the following as a base.

> Ingredients: onion, garlic, spices (black pepper, parsley, basil, marjoram, oregano, thyme, cayenne pepper, coriander, cumin, mustard, rosemary).

However, **not all** Mrs. Dash products are vegan. For example, the [Mrs. Dash Sweet Teriyaki Marinade](http://www.mrsdash.com/products/marinades/%C2%AE-sweet-teriyaki-marinade) includes honey as an ingredient.